# Did Missy cause the Solar Flare?

Tags: doctor-who

In the episode *In the Forest of the Night* the Doctor comments that he didn't see the Solar Flare coming which is suggested to be strange. When the Solar Flare hits Earth there is a shot of Missy watching the whole thing unfold from an iPad commenting

> that was surprising

and seems disappointed. Considering Missy's plan in *Death in Heaven* for the rest of humanity is there any evidence that the reason The Doctor didn't see the Solar Flare coming was because it was her doing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Given the expectations of Missy in *Death in Heaven*, it is unlikely she would have caused the solar flare. Considering her previous bouts of insanity, it may have simply been the disappointment of the unexpected petering out without serious incidence.

- Given the Doctor's surprise at the existence of the tree-like organism *In The Forest of The Night*, it is a possibility Missy didn't know of the tree-entities existence either.

> Since she had planned to give the Doctor an army of seven billion plus Cybermen and have the two of them rampage across the universe, it would seem less than ideal to destroy the Earth before her plan could come to fruition.